# SQL Server: Select records based on two boolean parameters from the same table

Tags: sql-server, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have a table like this :

```
ID ReceivedSalary ReceivedBonus
-------------------------------
1  true          true
2  true          false
3  false         true
4  false         false
```

I wanted to write a query based on both the Boolean parameters (`ReceivedSalary`, `ReceivedBonus`) i.e for the condition `ReceivedSalary=true` and `ReceivedBonus=true` output shall be 1st record and 3rd record as well. I need the second condition to be executed irrespective of the first condition.

How can I write a query with both the boolean parameters by omitting the first parameter if that doesn't yield any results and vice versa ?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a homework assignment?

Comment: No its not. I have a complex view thats returning me a dataset like the one mentioned in the question. When i try to do select *  from table where ReceivedSalary=true and ReceivedBonus=true it gives me nothing

Comment: Ah. You didn't mention that you already tried the obvious thing ;) Do you get correct results when you add only one condition? Perhaps the type of the columns is string instead of boolean. That could cause it not to match results (the string "true" would not necessarily be equal to the boolean value true)

Comment: No thats noat the issue, i have tried all possible combinations. I paraphrased my question. Please take a look.

Comment: Your desired results just need `ReceivedBonus=true`. What is the use of the other condition?

Comment: Right. how can i write a query with both the boolean parameters by omitting the first parameter if that doesn't yield any results ?

Comment: As Martin suggests, it does sound like the first parameter doesn't matter, but your last comment makes me think you can achieve what you need by running a query with both conditions and just run another query  when the first one does not return anything. I'm pretty sure the same could be achieved with a clever join in one query, but it would just be more confusing.

Comment: Include your desired output in tabular format.